# Django - IntegrityError ... NOT NULL constraint failed on save()

Tags: python, django, django-templates, cs50

I'm very new to Python and Django so please bear with me. I'm running into a persistent error traced back to the "saleitem.save()" line in the below views.py. I'm trying to create a form that will allow me to populate various fields and then save and display that information on an active_listing.html page.

**views.py**

```
def create_listing(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        saleitem = Listing()
        saleitem.user = request.user
        saleitem.item =request.POST.get("item")
        saleitem.description = request.POST.get("description")
        saleitem.category = request.POST.get("category")
        saleitem.bid = request.POST.get("bid")
        saleitem.image = request.POST.get("image_upload")
        saleitem.save()
        listings = Listing.objects.all()
        empty = False
        if len(listings) == 0:
            empty= True
        return render(request, "auctions/active_listing.html",{
            "listings": listings,
            "empty": empty
    })

    else: 
        return render(request, "auctions/create_listing.html")
```

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Listing(models.Model):
    saleitem = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="seller", null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(blank = True, max_length= 60)
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    image = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    listing_status = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default= True)
    winning_bidder = models.ForeignKey(User, blank= True, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name = "winner", null = True)    
    bidding_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

I've tried using a Django form rather than an html template as well and run into the same issue. When I populate all the fields in my html form and hit the save button, I run into an error:

IntegrityError at /create_listing
NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_listing.bid

Could anyone point me in the right direction of what to fix? The error message says the issue is with auctions_listing.bid but the traceback points to saleitem.save(). Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It is likely your `request.POST.get("bid")` returns NULL which is why `.save()` can't work because bid is not supposed to be null according to your model

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal thank you, I took a look at that and made sure the field was populated, but still am getting the same error. I modified the models bid object within the Listings class as such:     `bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=1, null=False {NOTE: I also tried True here just to see both ways and the same error persists})`. Do I need to make the modification in the views.py?

Comment: Can help to print `saleitem` and all it's attributes before the `.save()` command

Comment: Thanks for your guidance -- I ended up fixing the models.py to an IntegerField ' bid =  models.IntegerField(null=True)' which is not ideal but still within the spec of my assignment. This helped the saleitems.save() to work